# class annotations vs interface for persistence API

Tags: java, oop, google-app-engine, design-patterns

I'm developing an java API for persistence of objects where y use annotations for the fields, but i'm not sure what would be the better implementation regarding to Classes.

```
public interface Persistent{        
        public Key getKey();
    public void setKey(Key key);
}
public class PersistentObject implements Persistent{
    Key key;        
    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key=key;
    }       
}
```

OR

```
public @interface Persistent {  
}
@Persistent
public class PersistentObject {
    Key key; //the coder must create this variable or the system doesn't work
}
```

1. The firs one use the interface mechanism that is widely used in OOP,
   it requires to create a variable to implement this interface but is
   supposed the    progammer knows it.
2. The second is easier for the final programmer and is widely used in many
   libraries for persistence however forces the programmer to create a
   variable with one name by convention  that doesn't fit in the OOP
   model.

Thanx for your  answers.

Comment: well I have finally decided to go through the interface way since it's much more easier for me to code probably I will refactor it later to work with class annotations as it's the facto in similar libraries but I don't watch another advantage that it is easy for code to the final user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I am not going to give  you a answer. But I suggest that you go through the chapter ["Prefer annotations to naming patterns"](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22Prefer%20annotations%20to%20naming%20patterns%22&source=bl&ots=D3xd-6pEGj&sig=mGWjDkMoLmzRsqGt4AIkjetl2oM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1tRiUNyID8yJrAet1IDgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Prefer%20annotations%20to%20naming%20patterns%22&f=false) in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Please let me know if that's the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer is very useful since it solves the problem of naming the "key" variable just adding another annotation to it however I want to focus about the class itself.